# SLCertVerificationError with Conda Install and SpeechBrain Separately

Tags: python, ssl, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install ipykernel by running

`conda install -c anaconda ipykernel`

When I do so I get the error shown below.

```
CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anaconda/osx-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Separately, when I run the SpeechBrain code below in a jupyter notebook

```
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderClassifier
import speechbrain as sb
from speechbrain.dataio.dataio import read_audio
from IPython.display import Audio
from speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderDecoderASR
from speechbrain.pretrained import SepformerSeparation as separator
import os

model = separator.from_hparams(source="speechbrain/sepformer-wsj02mix", savedir='pretrained_models/sepformer-wsj02mix')
est_sources = model.separate_file(path='speechbrain/sepformer-wsj02mix/test_mixture.wav')
```

I get this error

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /speechbrain/sepformer-wsj02mix/resolve/main/custom.py (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

I did a fresh install of anaconda, but that did not help. Below is also my conda configuration with my username starred out.

```
add_anaconda_token: True
add_pip_as_python_dependency: True
aggressive_update_packages:
  - ca-certificates
  - certifi
  - openssl
allow_conda_downgrades: False
allow_cycles: True
allow_non_channel_urls: False
allow_softlinks: False
allowlist_channels: []
always_copy: False
always_softlink: False
always_yes: None
anaconda_upload: None
auto_activate_base: True
auto_stack: 0
auto_update_conda: True
bld_path: 
changeps1: True
channel_alias: https://conda.anaconda.org
channel_priority: flexible
channels:
  - defaults
client_ssl_cert: None
client_ssl_cert_key: None
clobber: False
conda_build: {}
create_default_packages: []
croot: /Users/***/opt/anaconda3/conda-bld
custom_channels:
  pkgs/main: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/r: https://repo.anaconda.com
  pkgs/pro: https://repo.anaconda.com
custom_multichannels:
  defaults: 
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
    - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
  local: 
debug: False
default_channels:
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r
default_python: 3.9
default_threads: None
deps_modifier: not_set
dev: False
disallowed_packages: []
download_only: False
dry_run: False
enable_private_envs: False
env_prompt: ({default_env}) 
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/***/opt/anaconda3/envs
  - /Users/***/.conda/envs
error_upload_url: https://conda.io/conda-post/unexpected-error
execute_threads: 1
experimental_solver: classic
extra_safety_checks: False
force: False
force_32bit: False
force_reinstall: False
force_remove: False
ignore_pinned: False
json: False
local_repodata_ttl: 1
migrated_channel_aliases: []
migrated_custom_channels: {}
non_admin_enabled: True
notify_outdated_conda: True
number_channel_notices: 5
offline: False
override_channels_enabled: True
path_conflict: clobber
pinned_packages: []
pip_interop_enabled: False
pkgs_dirs:
  - /Users/***/opt/anaconda3/pkgs
  - /Users/***/.conda/pkgs
proxy_servers: {}
quiet: False
remote_backoff_factor: 1
remote_connect_timeout_secs: 9.15
remote_max_retries: 3
remote_read_timeout_secs: 60.0
repodata_fns:
  - current_repodata.json
  - repodata.json
repodata_threads: None
report_errors: None
restore_free_channel: False
rollback_enabled: True
root_prefix: /Users/***/opt/anaconda3
safety_checks: warn
sat_solver: pycosat
separate_format_cache: False
shortcuts: True
show_channel_urls: None
signing_metadata_url_base: None
solver_ignore_timestamps: False
ssl_verify: True
subdir: osx-64
subdirs:
  - osx-64
  - noarch
target_prefix_override: 
track_features: []
unsatisfiable_hints: True
unsatisfiable_hints_check_depth: 2
update_modifier: update_specs
use_index_cache: False
use_local: False
use_only_tar_bz2: False
verbosity: 0
verify_threads: 1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the ssl verification by

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).